# Where can I get Glusterfs-hadoop plugin jar/rpm file?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-plugins, glusterfs

Where can I get Glusterfs-hadoop plugin jar/rpm file, for Hadoop-1.2.1 ?
I cannot compile the source at github.com/gluster/glusterfs-hadoop . 
The compile breaks.

Can anybody suggest a like to download the jar directly or the rpm ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got a link for some plugins:

http://rhbd.s3.amazonaws.com/maven/index.html